# Is following sets form a basis for $V^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the real vector space of all polynomials, in a single
 variable and with real coefficients, of degree at most $3$.

> Let $V^*$  be its dual space.
>
> Let $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 3, x_4 = 4.$

Is following sets of functionals $\{f_i |1 \leq i \leq 4\}$
 form a basis for $V^*$?

> For all $p \in V , f_i(p) =
>  p(x_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq 3$ and $f_4(p)=\int_{1}^{2} p'(x)dx$ |Yes/NO

## My attempt : i think Yes

i take  $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 $  and  $p '(x) = a_1 + 2a_2x + 3a_3x^2$ Then by integration: 
$$f_4(p)=\int_a^bp'(x)dx=a_1x+\frac{2a_2 x^2}{2}+\frac{3a_3x^3}{3} \ \ ]_a^b=  a_1(b-a) + a_2( b-a)^2 +a_3(b-a)^3$$ where $a=1 , b=2$

Now $f_1(p) = p(x_1)=a_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_1^2 + a_3x_1^3$

$f_2(p) = p(x_2)=a_0+a_1x_2+a_2x_2^2 + a_3x_2^3$

$f_3(p) = p(x_3)=a_0+a_1x_3+a_2x_3^2 + a_3x_3^3$

Now  for basis it must be linearly independent

so $f = c_1 f_1 + c_2f_2 + c_3 f_3 + c_4f_4=0 $ here $c_1=c_2=c_3=c_4 = 0$
so It will form a basis for $V^*$

Is is its True ?

Comment: Why do you think the integral of $f_4$ evaluates to $p(b-a)$ instead of $p(b)-p(a)$?

Comment: @almagest  because $p(b-a) =  p(b) - p(a)$

Comment: Really? Suppose $p(x)=x^2$. You think $(2-1)^2=2^2-1^2$?

Comment: okss @almagest i missed that logics

Comment: So how does that affect the rest of your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have $f_1(p)=p(1), f_2(p)=p(2), f_3(p)=p(3)$ and $f_4(p)=p(2)-p(1)$, and we need to check if they are linearly independent. But it looks like $f_4=f_2-f_1$.

So it's no.

Comment: Close.  For instance,  you could write $f_1-f_2+0\cdot f_3+f_4=0$.  That's a _nontrivial_ linear combination.   Right?

Comment: ya  @Chris custer thanks u